# Can I change the value of srcId and dstId of an edge in GraphX?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Is there any way to change the values of srcId and dstId of an edge, because when I do that:

```
val newGraph = graph.mapEdges(
      e =>
        if(//a condition here) {
          e.srcId*0 + //a value
          e.dstId*0 + //another value
          e.attr*1.0 //so that the attribute will remain the same
        }
    else {
          //another piece of code here
        }
    )
```

the srcId and dstId of the newGraph have the same values as graph. Note that the condition in the if statement works 100% (tested) and that the new values of the ids do exist in the graph, meaning that there is no case the new id will point to a vertex that do not exist. Also, a change of the edge attribute works with that piece of code, only the ids do not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `mapEdges`, same as other transformations on a `GraphImpl` (`mapTriplets`, `mapVertices`) is designed only to map attributes. To quote [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.impl.GraphImpl):

> Transforms each edge attribute using the map function, passing it a whole partition at a time. (...) and it should return a new iterator over the new values of each edge. The new iterator's elements must correspond one-to-one with the old iterator's elements.

As far as I know at this moment there is no way to modify sources or destinations without recreating a whole graph.

Comment: Thank you, I`ll try to find another way (by recreating a graph as you said)!!

Comment: My pleasure. I could've missed something but my guess is that rationale is pretty much the same as described by Matei Zaharia [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Incrementally-add-remove-vertices-in-GraphX-td2227.html) - GraphX is _meant for analysis once you have a graph_.